# collapse consecutive periods if the same

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, aggregate, period

I tried to express my use case in R code as follows:

```
haves <- data.frame(
          id = c(1,1,1,1)
        , start = c(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-02-01'), as.Date('2022-02-01'), as.Date('2022-02-16'))
        , end = c(as.Date('2022-01-31'), as.Date('2022-02-28'), as.Date('2022-02-15'), as.Date('2022-02-28'))
        , category = c("A", "B", "A", "A")
    )

haves
```

[image]

```
wants <- data.frame(
          id = c(1,1,1)
        , start = c(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-02-01'), as.Date('2022-02-01'))
        , end = c(as.Date('2022-01-31'), as.Date('2022-02-28'), as.Date('2022-02-28'))
        , category = c("A", "B", "A")
    )

wants
```

[image]

Basically I want to collapse time periods (see last 2 columns in wants) if they are consecutive and contain the same category but also depended on id. Do you think this is possible? A group by id and category and then using min and max on start and end would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rle`, this should work:

```r
r <- rle(haves$category)$l
haves %>% 
  mutate(cons = rep(seq(r), r)) %>% 
  group_by(id, category, cons) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(start),
            end = max(end))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   id, category [2]
     id category  cons start      end       
  <dbl> <chr>    <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1 A            1 2022-01-01 2022-01-31
2     1 A            3 2022-02-01 2022-02-28
3     1 B            2 2022-02-01 2022-02-28
```

Or with `cons = data.table::rleid(category)`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work but let me know if you have any issues.

First create an ID for blocks of consecutive rows within id & category, then find the blocks within these that are consecutive.

```
haves %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
      g_id = cumsum( paste0(id, '|', category) !=  lag(paste0(id, '|', category), n = 1L, default = '&%' ))
  ) %>%
  group_by(id, category, g_id) %>%
  mutate(
    lag1 = replace_na(lag(end, n = 1L)+1 == start, T)
    ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    g_id2 = cumsum( paste0(g_id, '|', lag1) !=  lag(paste0(g_id, '|', lag1), n = 1L, default = '&%' ))
  ) %>%
  group_by(id, category, g_id2) %>%
  summarise(
    start = min(start),
    end = max(end)
  ) %>%
  arrange(g_id2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)

unique(
  setDT(haves)[
    ,
    `:=`(start = min(start), end = max(end)), rleid(category)
  ]
)
```

gives

```
   id      start        end category
1:  1 2022-01-01 2022-01-31        A
2:  1 2022-02-01 2022-02-28        B
3:  1 2022-02-01 2022-02-28        A
```